# Issues with an Array.forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, owl-carousel

Hope someone here would be able to help me out.

I am trying to build an Owl-Carousel from an array of objects.
but for some reason the array is not been recognized, would appreciate if someone could help to find the mistake I have made here.

The error messages I am getting is:

> 'item' is not defined.
> and
> 'tv' is assigned a value but never used.

Here you have the code:

```
const tv = [
    {
        name: 'Meu Pedacinho de Chao 01',
        personagem: 'Barbeiro',
        ano: 2014,
        de: 'Benedito Ruy Barbosa',
        img: { mpc1 },
        alt: 'Meu Pedacinho de Chao 01'
     
    }...
    
]

export class Televisao extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class='container-fluid' >
                tv.forEach(function (item) {
                    <OwlCarousel items={3}
                        className="owl-theme"
                        loop
                        nav
                        margin={8} >

                        <div className='item card' >
                            <img className='"card-img-top" ' src={item.img} alt={item.alt} />
                            <div className='card-body' >
                                <h5 className="card-title" > ${item.name} </h5>
                                < p class="card-text" > ${item.personagem} </p>
                                < p class="card-text" > ${item.ano} </p>
                                < p class="card-text" > ${item.de} </p>
                            </div >
                        </div >
                    </OwlCarousel >
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Televisao;
```

Comment: forEach doesnt return anything. you will need to use map instead

Comment: tv.map((item) => (
  <OwlCarousel...
))

You might need to brush up on forEach and map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any expression Javascript should be inside curly brackets "{}" and replace forEach by map cause forEach doesn't return anything and I notice that you use a function and doesn't return anything to fix this you can add return before OwlCarousel component or use arrow function with parentheses.

```
const tv = [
    {
        name: 'Meu Pedacinho de Chao 01',
        personagem: 'Barbeiro',
        ano: 2014,
        de: 'Benedito Ruy Barbosa',
        img: { mpc1 },
        alt: 'Meu Pedacinho de Chao 01'
     
    }...
    
]

export class Televisao extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                {tv.map((item)=>(
                    <OwlCarousel items={3}
                        className="owl-theme"
                        loop
                        nav
                        margin={8}>
                        <div className="item card" >
                            <img className="card-img-top" src={item.img} alt={item.alt} />
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h5 className="card-title">{item.name}</h5>
                                <p className="card-text">{item.personagem}</p>
                                <p className="card-text">{item.ano}</p>
                                <p className="card-text">{item.de}</p>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                    </OwlCarousel>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Televisao;
```

Comment: Hi Ossama, tks a lot for helping me out.

But I am still getting an error, which I can not understand... doing the fixes you mentioned I get the folloing error:
>Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (61:17)

```
60: </OwlCarousel >
61:                )}
62:           </div>
```

It does not recognise that I am closing the Brackets on {tv.map... and ask me to add a comma ( , ), I do not understand why should I put a comma in this line and even if try to add the comma, other issues are presented.

Comment: I Have manage to fix it!!!

Comment: I edited the code, I notice that you are using class in JSX which confuse javascript between class of OOP and class of html so replace it with className. Tags should be written lik that <tag></tag> or <tag />

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` executes a function for every element, you want `map` in this case (and have to return the JSX from the function, which you're not currently doing)

```
const tv = [
    {
        name: 'Meu Pedacinho de Chao 01',
        personagem: 'Barbeiro',
        ano: 2014,
        de: 'Benedito Ruy Barbosa',
        img: { mpc1 },
        alt: 'Meu Pedacinho de Chao 01'
     
    }...
    
]

export class Televisao extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div class='container-fluid' >
                tv.map(function (item) {
                    return (<OwlCarousel items={3}
                        className="owl-theme"
                        loop
                        nav
                        margin={8} >

                        <div className='item card' >
                            <img className='"card-img-top" ' src={item.img} alt={item.alt} />
                            <div className='card-body' >
                                <h5 className="card-title" > ${item.name} </h5>
                                < p class="card-text" > ${item.personagem} </p>
                                < p class="card-text" > ${item.ano} </p>
                                < p class="card-text" > ${item.de} </p>
                            </div >
                        </div >
                    </OwlCarousel >)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Televisao;
```